# Map same key and value using google collections

Tags: java, apache, dictionary, guava

I need to validate if map (String to String) entry doesn't contain same key and value pair (case-insensitive). For example -

```
("hello", "helLo") // is not a valid entry
```

I was wondering if Google collection's `Iterable` combined with `Predicates` some how could solve this problem easily.

Yes I could have simple iterator for entries to do it myself, but thinking of any thing already up.

Looking for something in-lined with `Iterables.tryFind(fromToMaster, Predicates.isEqualEntry(IGNORE_CASE)).isPresent()`

Comment: do you need a boolean value whether the map contains any invalid entry? or do you want a filtered map?

Comment: I would throw the exception in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use guava, you can use the `Maps` utils, specifically the `filterEntries` function.

An example to filter only entries where the key does not equal the value (ignoring the case) could look like this

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("hello", "helLo");
map.put("Foo", "bar");

Map<String, String> filtered = Maps.filterEntries(map, new Predicate<Map.Entry<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Map.Entry<String, String> input) {
        return !input.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(input.getValue());
    }
});

System.out.println(filtered); // will print {Foo=bar}
```

However there is no default Predicate in guava's `Predicates` I know of that does what you want.

**Addition:**

If you want a validation mechanism without creating a new map, you can use `Iterables` and the `any` method to iterate over the entry set of the map. To make the condition more readable I would assign the predicate to a variable or a member field of the class you are working in.

```
Predicate<Map.Entry<String, String>> keyEqualsValueIgnoreCase = new Predicate<Map.Entry<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Map.Entry<String, String> input) {
        return input.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(input.getValue());
    }
};

if (Iterables.any(map.entrySet(), keyEqualsValueIgnoreCase)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

or if you need the entry, you can use the `Iterables#tryFind` method and use the returned `Optional`

```
Optional<Map.Entry<String, String>> invalid = Iterables.tryFind(map.entrySet(), keyEqualsValueIgnoreCase);

if(invalid.isPresent()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid entry " + invalid.get());
}
```

Comment: Won't its creating new Map? I mean extra overhead of Map construction?

Comment: I think simple entry iteration could be more efficient than this implementation, unless I'm missing anything?

Comment: yes. i added an alternative approach that avoids creating a map and throws an exception.

Comment: I know I'm demanding extra, but can we get the entry in return (may be as a String) which leads to the IllegalStateException? I want to display it so that user can get extra information where they fail.

Comment: yes, then you need the `tryFind` method and handle the `Optional`. i added another example :-)

Comment: Thank you so much :). Nice APIs indeed.

Comment: `Maps.filterEntries` will not incur "extra overhead of Map construction."  `Maps.filterEntries` returns a view in constant time; it doesn't construct a whole new map structure.

Comment: Thanks Louis, that's very interesting. After having a closer look at the `FilteredEntryMap` mechanisms I made out my error. Guava is indeed a very nifty library! Also: feel free to clean up my answer